# Column modification date

Tags: sharepoint-online

this is my first day of work, I have zero skills in power apps, so I ask you for help, the task is next. I created a table in share point, it has two columns, I need that when changing in one column, the date of these changes appears in the other in the format dd.mm.yyyy. To solve this problem, I integrated power apps into my share point table, but I don't know how and what code I need to implement. If anyone has the necessary skills and free time, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it from diferent way.

- SharePoint lists has field to save these information, refer: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/modified-by-column/m-p/1252278
  You can define any format for this field, ex: "dd.mm.yyyy".
- Enable list version SharePoint Online, please refer: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-list-or-library-1555d642-23ee-446a-990a-bcab618c7a37

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint have OOTB columns called [Modified] and [Modified by], one is to record the latest modification time and the other is to record the username corresponding to the modification.
And you can enable the version that you can see the version history.